# Animating views

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a tableview with multiple rows.row values dynamically changes every 2 secs except last row .i like to add a rotating view in the last row. how to add a animating view in the last row? how to rotate a view inside a tableviewcell? i'm not looking for a UIActivityindicator. i want to rotate my view around z axis.

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by rotating. Around which axis? The answer will be very different depending on if you want to rotate around the x, y, or z axis (or a combination).

Comment: I think what Allen is trying to ask is "how do i show a UIActivityIndicator inside a tableview cell?"

Comment: No, im not looking for a UIActivityIndicator. i want to rotate a view around z axis.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at how to show a UIActivityIndicator inside a table view cell, then the solution is simple.

In your table view cell subclass create an instance of UIActivityIndicator and add it as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a subview to the cell view and present it with `presentModalViewController` although I am not sure if this will work in a non-fullscreen scenario.